# The area of all the points within the set defined as...

Tags: geometry

Let $C$ be  a set in two dimensions and let $Q(C)$ be the area of $C$ if $C$ has a finite area; otherwise let $Q(C)$ be undefined.

So if we have this set, the book says,

$$C = \{(x,y): 0 \leq x, 0 \leq y, x+y\leq1\}$$

$Q(C) = \frac{1}{2}$

I'm struggling to have the ideas or concepts in my head to easily establish or see that the area is 1/2.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram?

Comment: You are essentially asked to determine the area of a triangle that is defined by 3 inequalities in 2D euclidean space. Draw the triangle, calculate its area and you are done

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I see where I went wrong. Yes I did draw a diagram, but I forgot one thing, that x and y are constrained to the 1st quadrant. Thanks.

Comment: Can you put that answer up @AleksejsFomins so I can close the question out. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially asked to determine the area of a triangle that is defined by 3 linear inequalities in a 2D euclidean space. Draw 3 lines, color the half-spaces corresponding to the inequalities, the intersection of all 3 will be a triangle. Calculate its area and you are done